# How to create shared slots for alexa skills

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I need help with creating shared slots.
I visited the official page: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/create-a-slot-type-to-use-in-multiple-skills.html#api-endpoint-and-header

however, I am unable to understand how to initiate the process of creating shared slots. 
Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ask cli`, I assume you've already installed and configured it on your machine in order to deploy skill. If so - skip the first section:

1. Install `ask cli` tool according to [ASK CLI Quick Start](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/quick-start-alexa-skills-kit-command-line-interface.html)
2. Once it's installed and configured you need to generate auth token using your client-id and secret from your [Security Profile](https://developer.amazon.com/settings/console/securityprofile/overview.html), configured to [Use SMAPI](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/get-access-token-smapi.html#configure-lwa-security-profile):

`ask util generate-lwa-tokens --client-id <your-client-id> --client-confirmation <your-client-secret>`

3. It should open the website, click Allow and go back to the console, there should be something like:

```
The LWA tokens result:
{
  "access_token": "Atza|IwEBIJDuJivzzkceXtesWGS5tYIKRZlK0NKp9OWP8TXh4HlFSQxTiMD4V-1QeoSHa8C6(...)",
  "refresh_token": "Atzr|IwEBIOyzzw_7(...)",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "expires_at": "2020-06-03T13:21:04.922Z"
}
```

4. Copy the `access_token` and use it in Authentication header: `Authorization: Bearer access_token` in requests from the doc site you've linked.

Hint: you can obtain your `vendorId` here:

```sh
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.amazonalexa.com/v1/vendors' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer access_token'
```

Sample CURL request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://api.amazonalexa.com/v1/skills/api/custom/interactionModel/slotTypes/' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer access_token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
     "vendorId": "MBT******E",
     "slotType": {
         "name": "SharedSlot",
         "description": "Your shared slot'\''s description"
     }
  }'
```

and response:

```
{
    "slotType": {
        "id": "amzn1.ask.interactionModel.slotType.e4fc2751-e4be-48c5-9be0-cd193a2ffafb"
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping me out. I have created my shared slot. How can I use it my skill now? How do I link my slot with the created slot type in the dev console?

Comment: Just follow the steps from the doc: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/create-a-slot-type-to-use-in-multiple-skills.html#use-the-slot-type-api

Comment: and it looks you can access it only by defining usage in the interaction model (so the skill's JSON)

Comment: Also i am unable to list all the slot types using the command :
/v1/skills/api/custom/interactionModel/slotTypes?vendorId={vendorId}

Comment: although i enter my vendorId in it, it still returns "Invalid/epixred token"

Comment: maybe it's expired? It's valid for 1h, then you need to refresh it or create a new one